# Position of the "Apply" button in QDialogButtonBox

Tags: qt

I would like to have a `QDialogButtonBox` with three buttons in this particular order:

```
Ok | Apply | Cancel
```

Is it possible to reorder the buttons to put `Apply` in the center?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The button layout is platform specific.

```
Windows - Ok | Cancel | Apply
OS X - Apply | Cancel | Ok
KDE - Ok | Apply | Cancel
GNOME - Apply | Cancel | Ok
```

There is two way to force use non standard layout.

You can subclass `QProxyStyle` and reimplement [styleHint](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html#styleHint) method, to provide custom style for `QStyle::SH_DialogButtonLayout` styleHint.

```
class KdeStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
public:
    virtual int styleHint(StyleHint stylehint, const QStyleOption *opt, const QWidget *widget, QStyleHintReturn *returnData) const override
    {
        if (stylehint == SH_DialogButtonLayout)
            return QDialogButtonBox::KdeLayout;

        return QProxyStyle::styleHint(stylehint, opt, widget, returnData);
    }
};
```

Then apply custom style to application.

```
qApp->setStyle(new KdeStyle());
```

Another way to do it, is using stylesheets. [button-layout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#button-layout-prop) property specify the layout of buttons in a `QDialogButtonBox` or a `QMessageBox`. The possible values are 0 (`WinLayout`), 1 (`MacLayout`), 2 (`KdeLayout`), and 3 (`GnomeLayout`).

```
QDialogButtonBox *buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Apply | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);
buttonBox->setStyleSheet("* { button-layout: 2 }");
```

Comment: Do you have an official source about button ordering on different systems?